# How to make Ubuntu-firefox to spellcheck all installed languages whatsoever?

Tags: firefox, language-support

I installed Ubuntu and then added Hebrew. All my Hebrew texts written in Firefox have a red underline indicating non-existant spell error.

Trying to solve it, I changed spellchecking language to Hebrew and the red underline went away from Hebrew texts, but then started appearing to English text.

Changing it time and again for each language isn't a good solution. You might know a way to turn spell checking for all languages automatically?

Comment: First of all, it's not "Ubuntu-Firefox", it's just Firefox. Your question is all about Firefox, nothing Ubuntu related. So, the answer is irrespective of the OS Firefox is running on: There's a way to turn **off** spell check but not a way to turn all languages on and it makes no practical sense for a web browser, even if it seems convenient for you.

Comment: I don't agree it makes no practical sense. For someone who works multilingually all day, it can be very practical, but our time is precious so now one everyone shared an opinion, let's leave this question to its fate.

Comment: When Hebrew text is displayed in Firefox, does the Text Encoding (in the Firefox menu) change to Hebrew?

Comment: Did you select the appropriate language in the context menu of the text input field? I tend to switch between different languages and I always have to set the currently relevant one this way. Are the `myspell-he` and `firefox-locale-he` packages installed on the system in question?

Comment: No, and no. Might try installing these, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given it isn't possible to have spellchecking for both Hebrew and English in the current release (and turning it on for one dyes everything in Red for the other) my solution was to fully disable spell checking in Firefox.